# Postfix - Delete queue for secondary installation?

Tags: postfix

I have installed multiple Postfix on the same server. To delete the queue for the main I run the following command

```
postsuper -d ALL
```

How would I do the same but for the second installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can point `postsuper` at a different configuration file:

```
postsuper -c /second/config/directory -d ALL
```

Alternatively, you can set the `MAIL_CONFIG` environment variable to point `postsuper` at the directory containing the configuration files for your second installation. Once you do either of the above, it will use the correct queue directories.

Comment: Thanks, how would I also do this for postqueue -p I tried postqueue -p -c /etc/postfix-new11/

Comment: Yes, `postqueue` also supports a `-c` option. **Hint:** all of this is documented on the manual pages (`man postqueue`).